# Overflow X with max two rows

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid

I have question. How I can display this blue element only in two max rows. If I set flex-wrap to wrap, I can't control the number of rows.  I want only max two rows, these blueitems will be scroll along the x axis.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-btx8jz?file=src/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use `grid` . but if you want to have only two rows , the child elements become overflowed

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

with `flex` you can do it to solve your problem , if the `.parent` has a certain `height`.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.parent {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="child">1 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">2 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">3 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">4 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">5 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">6 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">7 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">8 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">9 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">2 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">3 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">4 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">5 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">6 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">7 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">8 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
    <span class="child">9 loremnxckvxckhv</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I need flexbox, because I use Swiper library, and Swiper use flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Change in width of box.

set width 750px or greater it

```
.container {
  width: 750px;  // Change
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid;

  overflow-x: scroll;  /* Add */
}

.parent {
  display: flex;

  flex-wrap: wrap;     /* Add */
  width: max-content;  /* Add */
}

.child {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;

  flex-basis: 6%;  /* Add */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answear but the list of items is dynamic, it doesn't work if there are more items for example 1000 item, I want always display this in two rows